# Questions On Using the Facebook SDK For my Website

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am currently building a technology and hacking news website along with tutorials. I believe I have set up all the Open Graph tags since it shows correctly when shared in Facebook. Here are my questions.

1. Do I need an App ID just for this? The Share Debugger says I need one, but this is not an app.
2. Do I really need the admins meta tag? I remember adding it to my website, but I can not find where I originally found it.
3. The quote plugin does not seem to be working on the main body which I assigned to the class "fb-quote."
4. And finally, does it look like I am doing the Open Graph tags and everything right for Facebook? I have never used them before.

Here is my index.php source code. Thank you for reading this!This page is in no way complete, and the colors are off so I can see the div tags. Here is the link to the actual site so you can test the quote plugin. [Ken's Tech Link](https://kenstech.link/)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US"
      itemscope 
      itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" 
      prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=yes,minimum-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" itemprop="description" content="Programming projects, blogging, computer security, and anything related to technology.">
    <meta name="keywords" itemprop="keywords" content="computer,science,diy,tech,technology,ken,clark,blog,programming,dev,projects,electronics,tutorial,tutorials">
    <meta name="author" itemprop="author" content="Ken Clark">

    <meta property="fb:admins" content="100006702279209" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Home | Ken&#039;s Tech Link" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://kenstech.link/" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://kenstech.link/content/images/favicon.png" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Ken&#039;s Tech Link" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Programming projects, blogging, computer security, and anything related to technology." />
    <meta itemprop="image" content="https://kenstech.link/content/images/favicon.png">
    <meta itemprop="typicalAgeRange" content="16-">
    <meta itemprop="publisher" content="Ken&#039;s Tech Link">
    <meta itemprop="contentRating" content="MPAA PG-13">

    <link rel="author" href="https://plus.google.com/117128704888871471789" />


    <!-- CSS Includes -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content/css/index.css">

    <!--[if IE]><link rel="shortcut icon" href="content/images/favicon32x32.ico" type="image/x-icon"><![endif]-->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="content/images/favicon.png" />

    <title>Home | Ken&#039;s Tech Link</title>

  </head>

  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
                              })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'UA-78291630-1', 'auto');
      ga('send', 'pageview');

    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      WebFontConfig = {

        google: { families: [ 'Open+Sans:400,400italic,700,700italic:latin' ] }

      };

      (function() {

        var wf = document.createElement('script');

        wf.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/webfont.js';

        wf.type = 'text/javascript';

        wf.async = 'true';

        var s = document.getElementByTagName('script')[0];

        s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);

      })();
    </script>

    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    <!-- How dare you look at my source code, you peasent! -->
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div class="main-menu-container">
        <div class="main-menu-item"><a href="https://kenstech.link/">Home</a></div>
        <div class="main-menu-item"><a href="/whoami.php">About Me</a></div>
        <div class="main-menu-item"><a href="/contact.php">Contact Me</a></div>
        <div class="main-menu-item">TEMP TXT</div>
      </div>
      <div id="maincontent" class="fb-quote">
        <h1>This page is still a work in progress. Please check back later.</h1>
        <p><b>You may view my blog in the meantime: <a href="/blog">Ken's Tech Link Blog</a></b></p>
      </div><!-- maincontent end -->
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
      <div class="footer-item-left">
        <div
             class="fb-like"
             data-share="true"
             data-width="300"
             data-show-faces="true">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-item-center">
        <p>This is temporary text that means nothing. Ignore it or else.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="footer-item-right">
        TEMP
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. My layout tends to be horrible since I am not an expert in markup. My main language is C++ :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need an App ID just for this? The Share Debugger says I need one, but this is not an app.

Only if you want share to be attributed to your app. Since you don’t have one to begin with, you can ignore this warning.

> Do I really need the admins meta tag?

Only if you use the Comments plugin, and want to be able to moderate those comments via the interface Facebook provides for that.

> The quote plugin does not seem to be working on the main body which I assigned to the class "fb-quote."

The example code in the documentation is significantly different from what you’ve tried.

`fb-quote` needs to be an *extra*, empty element. You are trying to wrap your whole content *into* it, which is definitively not what the example in the docs show.

> And finally, does it look like I am doing the Open Graph tags and everything right for Facebook?

If the debug tool is satisfied (no real errors, just warnings about stuff like app id and admins meta tag), and everything shows up as intended when shared – then probably yes :)

Go check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#tags to see what additional OG meta tags there are, and if you want to use them.

Comment: Thank you! That solved my problem. Now I just need to finish the site and add content.